# Android WebView: check if web page consumed a touch

Tags: android, webview, touch

If I touch my WebView, is there a way to check in my WebView if the content (the webpage) actually used/consumed the touch?

What I in this case would like to do: if user touches a margin at the side of the screen: if there is no button, href, etc. underneath (when the web content did not use/consume the touch): use it myself (in the WebView) to start an auto-scroll. I have access to / can change the content.