# Web view detect on touch only when no link is clicked android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I load static htmls & urls in webview. Also, my web view is clickable ,on its click intent is fired.

> I want to implement- when the link in url/html is clicked in webview
>   link should load in webview. But when webview is clicked and no link
>   is clicked intent should be fired.

**I need to implement onTouch listener on detect touch on webview & fire intent. But if I implement ontouch then the internal links are never opened in html/url of webview**

```
public class WebViewHotspotClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
//        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
//        return true; does not open link
        return false;//opens link in web view 
    }
}

    hotspotWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewHotspotClient());
//        hotspotWebview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
//            @Override
//            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
//                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
//                    startActivity(new Intent(ImageFrameActivity.this, HotspotActivity.class));
//                }
//                return false;
//            }
//        });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is when you assign ontouchlistener to the whole webview other elements go under it and they dont get any touch or click. To solve this problem you can do following

```
public class MyWebViewClicker extends Activity implements OnTouchListener,     Handler.Callback {

private static final int CLICK_WEBVIEW = 1;
private static final int CLICK_URL = 2;

private final Handler handler = new Handler(this);

private WebView webView;
private WebViewClient webviewclient;
boolean donext=false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.web_view);

webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myweb);
webView.setOnTouchListener(this);

webviewclient = new WebViewClient(){ 
    @Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { 
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(CLICK_URL);
        return false;
    } 
}; 

webView.setWebViewClient(webviewclient);
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.myweb && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)  {
    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(CLICK_WEBVIEW, 500);
}
return false;
}

@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
if (msg.what == CLICK_URL){
    Toast.makeText(this, "URL is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    donext=true;
    return true;
}
if (msg.what == CLICK_WEBVIEW){
    if(donext==true)
    { 
      //do nothing
    }else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "WebView is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    return true;
}
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks , this code is able to detect when the url is clicked but when after the url is clicked CLICK_WEBVIEW is also triggered immediately causing the intent to fire each time a url is clicked, Please help

Comment: I have added a boolean variable to check if url is clicked and if yes didnt do anything in webview_click. Edited answer. i think it will help you @RachitaNanda