# Webview is stealing the touch event - How to delegate the touch event to parent container of webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webview within a container which is draggable within the screen. I'd like to handle the touch event at the container level so that webview will be draggable around. However, Webview steals the touch (it basically scrolls down the rendered web site and container stays still, I want the site stays still and the parent container of webview should be moving around).

I tried a couple of methods so far like overriding the webview.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
{
    onTouchEvent(ev);
    return false;
}
```

This doesn't really worked. Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821565/check-if-android-webview-is-consuming-touch-events

Comment: Thanks for the comment but is not  helpful in my case @MorrisonChang sorry.